# I need to remove the two fields as mentioned in the screenshot from Magento 2

Tags: magento, configuration, attributes, magento2

As you can see in the screenshot, we have skin type and product brand with an asterik.
[image: Removing Product name and Skin Type asterik fields]

I have created a new attribute and I don't want these two field to be included in it. So how can I remove the field manually from the Magento dashboard or I can make it not mandatory to add.

Currently I have dragged skin type from Stores->Product Attributes->Groups to unassigned attributes.

Comment: If a (custom) attribute "Skin Type" shows up with a product config in admin, the product you are viewing has an attribute set that contains "Skin Type" under some group other than "unassigned". Can you please check that the product you are viewing actually has the attribute set you have configured with your new attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below steps to hide product fields

Step 1:

create catalog_product_edit.xml under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout

File: catalog_product_edit.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myattribHide" before="before.body.end" template="Vendor_Module::product/edit/fieldhide.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Step 2: Create file fieldhide.phtml under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/product/edit

File : fieldhide.phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'uiRegistry'
    ], function($,uiRegistry){
        uiRegistry.get("product_form.product_form.content.container_yourcustomfield.yourcustomfield", function (element) {
         element.hide();
      });        
    })
</script>
```

Note: Please replace "yourcustomfield" with your attribute code

Step 3: Please remove static files and refresh cache